# BIOS - randomly can't detect the HD boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, bios, ide

I have P4 IBM ThinkCentre (from 2004) and the BIOS detects the IDE HD. But sometimes boot in the WD caviar3200 is **not detected**.

However other times boot is detected and WindowsXP **works fine** for hours or even days.

Checking the HD, everything is OK on SMART and this issue started happening since a long time ago. So, I understand that HD is not in a bad state.

Regarding physical contacts, I unplugged/plugged IDE cable and even I had replaced IDE and power cables.
Also, I turned the PC case from vertical to horizontal (as designed) and yes, sometimes BIOS detected the boot and OS was loaded (PC and HD in horizontal). Unfortunately not always this technique worked, so it doesn't seem the problem.

DO you think it is a software or physical issue?
What about adding a new HD containing a multiple boot menu in its MBR and load the other HD from there.

Comment: When did the problem occur? Did this configuration work before? Did a different one work?

Comment: Originally the PC was placed in horizontal with same HD, and it never failed. Later PC was placed vertically and it worked fine for years, and at sometime the issue started.

Comment: I don't think it will have anything to do with the orientation but if it does, it's definitely faulty HW. Did you get a chance to try my suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First I would try to exchange HD, cable, etc. to see if the problem persists and to further isolate it. Maybe that will already give you the required solution.

So far it's not possible to pinpoint the problem without guessing - see my comment in your question. But if you want to "poke" around, and update BIOS, choose different BIOS settings etc. You might hit the right solution by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an old device upgrading the BIOS solved mine so, try upgrading yours to the latest available version, there is a big chance to solve your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The IBM BIOS has an automatic/alternative boot sequence (executed in case of error during the primary/normal one) so I enabled it.
I detected that most times that OS loaded it was during the second/automatic boot sequence but many times the HD was no loaded.

Then I moved the PC to horizontal position and since then the HD is always booting the OS, most times after failing default/normal boot sequence.

Maybe this HD need more time to move the headers or to reach the required rpm (especially on vertical position) and the HD is not ready when boot sequence reads from it.